# Google Tag Manager - one rule for several URLS?

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

I have several different landing pages I need to have the same pixels on, 
but don't want to have to create a new firing rule for each one - that would get unmanageable.

Its a shame that the URL firing conditions in GTM don't have an OR condition.

How can I create 1 rule but add multiple URLS?

Comment: Please provide sample data to write a regex for.

Comment: I would recommend using lookup tables for the variables to fire the triggers - or as above comment, add sample data so we can write a regex.